# How come my classpath isn't being used?

Tags: java, jar, java-package

I have `projects/plugin/target/mypackage.jar`

Then I have `projects/runner/Runner.java`

When I run `jar tf mypackage.jar`, it doesn't have some classes it relies upon. `Runner.java` wants to `import mypackage.MyClass`

When I do `javac -cp '.:../plugin/target/*' Runner.java` from the `runner` folder, it complains that some dependencies of `MyClass` aren't available.

My `runner` folder contains the appropriate JAR files. If I copy-paste those JAR files into `target` folder, the compilation works. Considering I'm using `.` in my classpath, why wouldn't the package know where to find the correct JARs?

Comment: Java JAR files always ignore the command line class path setting.  Use the MANIFEST.MFfile to set the class path for a JAR file.

Comment: Thanks Mark, let me look into both. If this is dupe, I will close.

Comment: Err why would it be that when I do `javac -help` or `java -help` it doesn't show `jar` as an option. `javac: invalid flag: -jar`

Comment: Definitely not a dupe btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some advice and shenanigans I found that this works:

`javac -cp './*:../plugin/target/*' Runner.java`.

The key difference being `./*` rather than `.`

If anyone can better explain why that is the case, I will gladly mark them as the answer.

Comment: Can't answer due to hold but [a _directory_ in the classpath is only used to find class files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/classpath.html#A1100592) while a jarfile name _or_ [a wildcard (NOT in manifest) is used to find jarfiles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/classpath.html#A1100762). Thus `.` finds classes but `./*` or `../plugin/target/*` finds jars, and your Q only mentioned wanting to find jars